# WPF: Can I get the size of a UIElement AFTER a transform is applied?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, transform, uielement

In WPF/Silverlight, can I get the calculated value of a `UIElement` after a transformation is applied?

(Per the comment below):

I've got a stack panel and I've applied a `TranformGroup` to it. There are two translate and one scale transforms in this group.

(warning, psuedo code ahead)

```
groupTransform.children.add(new TranslateTransform());
groupTransform.children.add(new ScaleTransform());
groupTransform.children.add(new TranslateTransform());
containerToScale.RenderTransform = groupTransform;
...
// code that sets values to all the transforms
```

Obviously the scale transform is the one I'm most interested in.

Comment: Applying a transform is too generic.  What exactly are you doing?  What properties, methods, etc. are achieving this transform?  Show us some code.

Answer (score 3):

Matthew, as you pointed out `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` don't change if you apply transforms. `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` represent the calculated width/height after the layout system has finished calculating the size of a control (based on values such as `Margin`, `HorizontalAlignment`, etc.)

One way to get the size of a control taking into account all of the scale transformations that have been applied to it is to walk up the visual tree and apply all scale transforms to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of a control:

```
public static Size GetActualSize(FrameworkElement control)
{
    Size startSize = new Size(control.ActualWidth, control.ActualHeight);

    // go up parent tree until reaching root
    var parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(control);
    while(parent != null && parent as FrameworkElement != null && parent.GetType() != typeof(Window))
    {
        // try to find a scale transform
        FrameworkElement fp = parent as FrameworkElement;
        ScaleTransform scale = FindScaleTransform(fp.RenderTransform);
        if(scale != null)
        {
            startSize.Width *= scale.ScaleX;
            startSize.Height *= scale.ScaleY;
        }
        parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
    }
    // return new size
    return startSize;
}

public static ScaleTransform FindScaleTransform(Transform hayStack)
{
    if(hayStack is ScaleTransform)
    {
        return (ScaleTransform) hayStack;
    }
    if(hayStack is TransformGroup)
    {
        TransformGroup group = hayStack as TransformGroup;
        foreach (var child in group.Children)
        {
            if(child is ScaleTransform)
            {
                return (ScaleTransform) child;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Keep in mind that this might be inefficient if your visual tree is deep or you perform this many times. In practice I've never run into any problems with this, however.

Answer (score 2):

you could simply apply the transform:

`control.LayoutTransform.Transform(new Point(0,0))`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` on any `FrameworkElement` to figure this out. You'll need to check whether it is visible though if you have elements that hide.

If you want to know after the control has loaded use the `Loaded` event.

Comment: I've checked and the StackPanel.ActualWidth and ActualHeight don't change as I apply a transformation to them. =-/